# How to fix wrong number of constraints in Django with psql prompt?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psql

I'm unable to migrate a model due to the following exception and I'm trying to fix the issue with `psql`.

```
ValueError: Found wrong number (2) of constraints for accounting_inventory(trade_id)
```

**models.py**

```
class Inventory(TimestampedModel):

    class Type(models.TextChoices):
        SNAPSHOT = 0, "Snapshot"
        ASSET = 1, "Asset"
        CONTRACT = 2, "Contract"

    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    trade = models.OneToOneField(Trade, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=64, choices=Type.choices)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    assets = models.JSONField(default=dict, null=True)
    contracts = models.JSONField(default=dict, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Inventory"
        unique_together = [('trade',), ]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)[-4:]
```

Now, Django says there is no migration:

```
root@1f3de954c6e0:/app# python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

Problem is when I remove the `unique_together` it generates this migration file but can't migrate because of the exception above.

**migration file**

```
root@1f3de954c6e0:/app# more accounting/migrations/0022_alter_inventory_unique_together.py 
# Generated by Django 4.0.6 on 2023-04-10 06:40

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounting', '0021_alter_inventory_unique_together_inventory_account_and_more'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
            name='inventory',
            unique_together=set(),
        ),
    ]
```

I connected with `psql` and found this when listing constraints:

```
defaultdb=> SELECT con.*
defaultdb-> FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint con
defaultdb-> INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class rel
defaultdb-> ON rel.oid = con.conrelid
defaultdb-> INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace nsp
defaultdb-> ON nsp.oid = connamespace
defaultdb-> WHERE nsp.nspname = 'public'
defaultdb-> AND rel.relname = 'accounting_inventory';
  oid  |                            conname                             | connamespace | contype | condeferrable | condeferred | convalidated | conrelid | contypid | conindid | conparentid | confrelid | confupdtype | confdeltype | confmatchtype | conislocal | coninhcount | connoinherit | conkey | confkey | conpfeqop | conppeqop | conffeqop | confdelsetcols | conexclop | conbin 
-------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------+---------------+-------------+--------------+----------+----------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------------+-----------+--------
 45847 | accounting_inventory_account_id_d03d3e05_fk_trading_account_id |         2200 | f       | t             | t           | t            |    20082 |        0 |    17118 |           0 |     17112 | a           | a           | s             | t          |           0 | t            | {24}   | {1}     | {410}     | {410}     | {410}     |                |           | 
 20288 | accounting_inventory_trade_id_5cf7c1af_fk_accounting_trade_id  |         2200 | f       | t             | t           | t            |    20082 |        0 |    20272 |           0 |     20267 | a           | a           | s             | t          |           0 | t            | {8}    | {3}     | {2972}    | {2972}    | {2972}    |                |           | 
 20106 | accounting_inventory_trade_id_5cf7c1af_uniq                    |         2200 | u       | f             | f           | t            |    20082 |        0 |    20105 |           0 |         0 |             |             |               | t          |           0 | t            | {8}    |         |           |           |           |                |           | 
 20089 | accounting_inventory_trade_id_key                              |         2200 | u       | f             | f           | t            |    20082 |        0 |    20088 |           0 |         0 |             |             |               | t          |           0 | t            | {8}    |         |           |           |           |                |           | 
 43164 | accounting_inventory_uuid_110c3781_pk                          |         2200 | p       | f             | f           | t            |    20082 |        0 |    43163 |           0 |         0 |             |             |               | t          |           0 | t            | {23}   |         |           |           |           |                |           | 
(5 rows)
```

And this:

```
defaultdb=> \d+ accounting_inventory
                                              Table "public.accounting_inventory"
   Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
-------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 dt_created  | timestamp with time zone |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 dt_modified | timestamp with time zone |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 trade_id    | uuid                     |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
 type        | character varying(64)    |           | not null |         | extended |             |              | 
 datetime    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |         | plain    |             |              | 
 assets      | jsonb                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 contracts   | jsonb                    |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
 id          | uuid                     |           | not null |         | plain    |             |              | 
 account_id  | bigint                   |           |          |         | plain    |             |              | 
Indexes:
    "accounting_inventory_uuid_110c3781_pk" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "accounting_inventory_account_id_d03d3e05" btree (account_id)
    "accounting_inventory_trade_id_5cf7c1af_uniq" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (trade_id)
    "accounting_inventory_trade_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (trade_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "accounting_inventory_account_id_d03d3e05_fk_trading_account_id" FOREIGN KEY (account_id) REFERENCES trading_account(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    "accounting_inventory_trade_id_5cf7c1af_fk_accounting_trade_id" FOREIGN KEY (trade_id) REFERENCES accounting_trade(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
Access method: heap
```

What should I do to fix the problem ? I notice there are two unique constraints in the db for `trade`:

```
accounting_inventory_trade_id_5cf7c1af_uniq
accounting_inventory_trade_id_key
```

Answer (score 1):

`unique_together` expects at least 2 fields. You've only given it one.

```
unique_together = [('trade',), ]
```

If you want just `trade` to be unique, use `unique=True` when you define the field.

Note also that `unique_together` is on its way out, and you should use the `constraints` option instead if you need this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: When I add another unique_together `[('trade', 'account'), ]` there was still the exception. Django should have prevent me from doing this mistake

Comment: Django isn't magic :) It can't stop you making mistakes. It can only tell you when something is wrong. From what you just added, you did exactly what I said, it just seemed there was an extra couple of steps needed - sometimes an issue is like that, but you have to take one thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by doing the following:

Delete inappropriate CONSTRAINTS :

```
ALTER TABLE public.accounting_inventory DROP CONSTRAINT accounting_inventory_trade_id_5cf7c1af_uniq;
ALTER TABLE public.accounting_inventory DROP CONSTRAINT accounting_inventory_trade_id_key;
```

Recreate CONSTRAINT with 2 columns:

```
defaultdb=> ALTER TABLE accounting_inventory ADD UNIQUE (trade_id, account_id);
```

Set unique_together in my models.py:

```
unique_together = [('trade', 'account',), ]
```

Then I generated the migration file migrated with the `--fake` option and it was fine.

Comment: As long as the only change in the latest migration was the constraint, you should be fine. See also my note about not using `unique_together` any more, and using the `constraints` option instead.